# Wordpress | Login with specific IP Adress for Administrator but not other users

Tags: wordpress, authentication

I asked myself if it would be possible to allow wordpress backend login for all users, but only the (only) administrator has to come from one destinct ip-adress? Does anyone have an idea?

Cheers
Manu

I tried to solve it with .htaccess entries, but I dont think, that this would be possible.

order deny,allow
        Deny from all
  
# Whitelist John as website administrator
allow from 35.199.128.0
  
#Whitelist Tina as Editor 
allow from 108.59.80.0
 
# Whitelist Ali as moderator
allow from 216.239.32.0

Comment: No, on the .htaccess level, the server has no idea which user might be about to log in. Using the [`wp_authenticate_user`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_authenticate_user/) hook to implement an additional check of the requesting IP address, when the user is the admin, might be your best bet.

Answer (score 0):

The best option I can see is to have load balancer in front of your Wordpress. This will not work though, if you use SaaS Wordpress, not your own installation.

For example, if you use HAProxy, you can configure the paths very granulary.

The point is to search for solutions to implement as early in the chain as possible. If you whitelist one IP in Wordpress, it will "secure" your installation, but you will be open for different nasty things like DDoS on the application level.

Give us more hint how your wordpress is installed, it will be easier to help :)